# vmcloak taking forever to start Windows when setting up Cuckoo

Tags: python, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, malware, cuckoo

I am trying to set up Cuckoo on an `Ubuntu 18.04.6` machine as per instructions on https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/configuration.html and https://hatching.io/blog/cuckoo-sandbox-setup/ but one of the commands is taking forever.

Running the command `vmcloak init --verbose --win7x64 win7x64base --cpus 2 --ramsize 2048`  takes forever. I've been waiting for 3 hours and running `vmcloak list vms` shows nothing. Any help is appreciate or let me know if you need more information thank you!

Comment: this is where its stuck at after running `vmcloak init --verbose --win7x64 win7x64base --cpus 2 --ramsize 2048 `



`/home/user/cuckootest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:14: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography import utils, x509
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
INFO:vmcloak:Starting the Virtual Machine u'win7x64base' to install Windows.`

Answer (score 0):

After running the command try to open Vbox gui and install it itself. I got stucked at language choice

Answer (score 0):

What i did was to switch to "Ubuntu Desktop" and reinstalling virtualbox:

To switch to "Ubuntu Desktop", type:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

After that, you'll have to reboot the VM. Reinstall virtualbox:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox
```

Try to rerun your vmcloak installation.